# Foreground color of a text in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a function to return the color codes of a text in a cell.

Code that I came up with:

```
function FCOLOR(input) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Workspace").getActiveCell().getFontColors();
}
```

2. when I type the function, like below it should return the color code in the cell where I use it:
   `=FCOLOR(A1)`

The code is working without any errors, but it is not giving the correct color codes, it is reflecting #00000.

Please help me out here, what could've possibly gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function FCOLOR(input) {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(input).getFontColors();
}
```

and in the spreadsheet pass the range as a string. E.g:

```
=FCOLOR("A2:A4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use with parameter like this

```
function FCOLOR(row, column) {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getCell(row, column).getFontColors();
}
```

> Get the font color with this formula

```
=FCOLOR(ROW(A2),COLUMN(A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by giving the following formula

```
=FCOLOR("A2:A",A2:A)
```